# Adding column to list view in particular order

Tags: list, list-view

I have couple of sites and each contains a list. I'd like to add Title field to default view in each of those lists but I want them to be 3rd column in the view. Since I couldn't find anything similar to the web-based editor of sharepoint list views, where one can choose in what order should columns be displayed, I'm asking for some guidance and/or help with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for code solution my approach would be to remove all fields from view and then add them in desired order.

Here is one simple example:

[Change The Fields Order In The Sharepoint View Programmatically](http://blog.sharedove.com/adisjugo/index.php/2011/01/30/change-the-fields-order-in-the-sharepoint-view/)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the article on my blog on Difference between SharePoint List Views and List Column Ordering at http://tad.co.in/?p=588